# Squared cosine integral transform

Tags: integral-transforms

Does anybody know where can I find information about squared cosine/squared sine integral transform:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \cos^2 (zx) dx$$

I want to see the list of such transforms over functions and/or know how to implement it in Mathematica.

Comment: by the double angle formula this transformation is equivalent to the usual cosine transform (if we had the standard integral over the infinite interval)

Comment: @tired I tried cosine transform and it gives 0 for function $\cos^2(x)$. I think it should give DiracDelta[1+x]

Comment: That is just the usual Fourier (cosine) transform in disguise.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio I cannot express it via cosine transform. You can?

Comment: @Anixx: just exploit $$\cos^2(xz) = \frac{1+\cos(2xz)}{2}$$ and a change of variable ($2z=\omega$).

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio and what? How it will produce the first term?